# Why ST_Equals for same geometries returns false?

Tags: sql, postgresql, gis, postgis

Why *ST_Equals* for same objects (one from geometry column and another from geojson extracted from the same geometry column) returns false?

Ex.:

```
select st_equals(geom, st_setsrid(st_geomfromgeojson(st_asgeojson(geom)), 2180)) from city
```

Definition of column *geom* is:

```
ALTER TABLE city ADD COLUMN geom geometry(MultiPolygon,2180);
```

**EDIT:**

Query with st_asgeojson(geom, 999999999) also not working

```
select st_equals(geom, st_setsrid(st_geomfromgeojson(st_asgeojson(geom, 999999999)), 2180)) from city
```

**EDIT2:**

Reproducible example:

```
SELECT st_equals(geom, st_setsrid(st_geomfromgeojson(st_asgeojson(geom, 999999999)), 2180))
FROM
  (SELECT st_geomfromewkb(decode('AQYAACCECAAABAAAAAEDAAAAAQAAAAsAAAAPqGkZxtsfQR+Tq/icNydBNwTIEZsUIEF/uKr0AfIm
QTsvQxUcvB9Bdw1O9C7IJkEVnpoEBD0fQcFK5/MexSZBwMHT9KXEHkFNt8zxIdwmQezy8+91nx5B
JW6L+tkeJ0G68RXtlYkeQdnY3QSabSdB7MjG/EsBH0FuiKD6qpQnQczdMBNOrB9BK783BvmeJ0GO
URITcx4gQbSMcQaieSdBD6hpGcbbH0Efk6v4nDcnQQEDAAAAAQAAAAUAAABERDkK5GcfQdNUQuem
ZCZBkJbI/psQH0FUMIjfsikmQQDtYP3jBR9BVr0n5jpcJkHS02H+iw0fQQL74OyGjyZBREQ5CuRn
H0HTVELnpmQmQQEDAAAAAQAAAAUAAAAkHKMesHYgQTy3RfkU7iZBi9UrHiJzIEG7SVjr0oMmQR/r
kBTaKSBBH3xW6YJ0JkHnHCARmg8gQbVkpO76nCZBJByjHrB2IEE8t0X5FO4mQQEDAAAAAQAAAAUA
AAA8b3IhIIwgQcCpIQq1bidBINh3JxC6IEFwnmYBGSwnQYN91h44eCBB6PT+/2AhJ0HeIjUWYDYg
QQi4hQfNWidBPG9yISCMIEHAqSEKtW4nQQ==', 'base64')) geom) a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[st_asGeoJson](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html) reduces coordinates decimals to 9 digits by default. Should the source geometry have more digits, the transformed geometry is therefore different.

Also geometries are saved using double precision, with 15 significant digits. If your data (input) has less, the remaining digits are still set but can be considered as noise... however this noise is exported/imported back, and can be slightly different than the input.

The simplest to overcome this is to [snap](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html) the coordinates to a grid, whose size is your input precision. You should do the snap on the source geometry (when adding the data to your DB), and when reading the geojson

```
st_equals(ST_SnaptoGrid(geom,5),ST_SnaptoGrid(st_setsrid(st_geomfromgeojson(st_asgeojson(ST_SnaptoGrid(geom,5))), 2180),5))
```

Comment: I know it, but geometry has not more digits, I also tried to extract geometry with function st_asgeojson(geom, 999999999) and still not working.

Comment: @TarasMelon It would have helped to have a reproducible example. Don't forget that coordinates are saved as floats which are no exact. So even if you haven't set them, noise can still be found in the decimals

Comment: please, see EDIT2, I added a reproducible example @JGH

Comment: @TarasMelon it doesn't make sense to use more than 15 significant digits. See solution using st_SnapToGrid